# $f(n)= \left\lfloor \frac{an+b}{cn+d} \right\rfloor , \forall n \in \mathbb N$ is surjective

Tags: functions, solution-verification, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb N , d \ne 0$ and consider the funtion $f: \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N $ such that : $$f(n)=\left \lfloor \frac{an+b}{cn+d}\right \rfloor , \forall n \in \mathbb N$$
Prove that $(c=0 , b < d , 0 < a \le d) \implies f$ is a surjective function

I tried to solve this Olympiad problem by myself. My solution is totally different from the one presented by the author, so it is difficult for me to self-evaluate. Can you please tell me if the solution below is complete and correct? And if you can give it a score from 0 to 7? Thanks !

My attempt :

Let's consider $c=0, b < d , 0 < a \le d$ , so the function becomes $f(n)=\left \lfloor \frac{an+b}{d}\right \rfloor , \forall n \in \mathbb N$ . Let $k \in \mathbb N$ such that $  f(n)=k \implies$ $$ \implies k = \left\lfloor \frac{an+b}{d}\right \rfloor \implies $$ $$\implies k \le \frac{an+b}{d} < k +1 \implies$$  $$ \implies kd \le an+b < kd + d \implies $$  (we can devide by $a$ since $a > 0$ ) $$\implies \frac{kd-b}{a} \le n < \frac{kd-b+d}{a} $$ Now I will prove that $n = \lfloor \frac{kd-b}{a} \rfloor + 1 $ checks the condition above. First , from the definition of the floor function it is obvious that $\lfloor \frac{kd-b}{a} \rfloor + 1 > \frac{kd-b}{a}$.Second , $\lfloor \frac{kd-b}{a} \rfloor + 1 \le \frac{kd-b}{a}+1 = \frac{kd-b+a}{a} < \frac{kd-b+d}{a}$. (**COMMENT** the inequality is strict because otherwise we would have $d=a$ and $kd-b$ is divisible by $a$ $\implies$ $b$ is divisible by $a$ but $b \le d = a \implies b = a $ , but $ b < d \implies$ false     )

So I proved that for an arbitrarily chosen $k \in \mathbb N$, there is an $n$ such that $f(n)=k \implies \forall k \in \mathbb N , \exists n = \lfloor \frac{kd-b}{a} \rfloor + 1 \in \mathbb N$ such that $f(n)=k \implies f$  is a surjective function.

Comment: @AnneBauval I don't know for sure, but I received it from a former Olympian friend, who is also preparing.

Comment: @CalvinLin , I approached the case when (kd-b)/a is an integer in the parenthesis where it says COMMENT. can you tell me if it is correct ?

Comment: d = a is essential to have equality in inequality

Comment: when (kd-b)/a is a integer $\implies$ for n = (kd -b)/a + 1  checks because (kd -b)/a < (kd -b)/a + 1 < (kd+d-b)/a . and the right side is strict if we don't have b = d, so we can choose this n= (kd -b)/a + 1 because it checks

Comment: It is easier to prove that $f(0)=0$ and $f(n)\leq f(n+1)\leq f(n)+1$ and $f(n)$ is unbounded. Then use this to prove that $f$ is surjective, using the well-ordering principle.

Comment: @AnneBauval , I can't find the 3 dots , but yes it should be written as "is divisible by"

Comment: What 3 dots? and  "(we can devide by $a$ since $a \ne 0$ )" should be "(we can d$\color{red}i$vide by $a$ since $a>0$)"

Comment: I found it ,I was referring to $\vdots$

Comment: Honestly, I find the argumentation quite messy, especially the COMMENT thing. Anyway, I am under the impression that the proof is written in the same ''chronological'' order that it was found and, formally, the proof is not correct as it. What you actually need is $(kd-b)/a \leq n < (kd-b+d)/a \ \Rightarrow \ f(n)=k$ and not $f(n)=k  \ \Rightarrow \  (kd-b)/a \leq n < (kd-b+d)/a$. Here, those are equivalent so it doesn't matter but for a proof, that's a little bit weird.

Comment: Personnally, I would have preferred the following structure. Let $k\in\mathbb{N}$. We show: 1) $(kd-b) \leq n < (kd-b+d)/a$ with $n =\lfloor (kd-b)/a \rfloor + 1$ and 2) this implies $f(n)=k$.

Comment: @Unknowduck I misread the condition as $d \leq a$, so my comments were not relevant. I have deleted them.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct but your argument for the strict inequality is a bit unclear. I'd rather say: let $u:=\frac{kd-b}a$ and $n:=\lfloor u\rfloor+1$. Then,
$$n\le u+1\le u+\frac da$$
and $n=u+\frac da$ is impossible because if it were the case, we would have $d=a$ and $$\frac bd=k-n+1\in\Bbb Z,$$
which is absurd since $0\le\frac bd<1$.

Edit1. After reading this answer, you improved well your argument for the strict inequality. I still find mine clearer.

Edit2. I won't score your proof.

Comment: Thank you for your help ! Can you tell me how much points I would have taken out of 7 points in a contest?

Answer (score 1):

A clearer, but non-constructive, proof is to show:

1. $f(0)=0,$
2. $f(n+1)\leq f(n)+1,$ and
3. $f(n)$ is unbounded above.

All of these are easy to prove.

Then we can show any function $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ which satisfies (1.), (2.), and (3.) is surjective.

Assume $m\in\mathbb N.$

If $m=0$ then $f(0)=0.$

If $m>0,$ let $S=\{n\in\mathbb N\mid f(n)\geq m\}.$ By (3.) $f$ is not bounded above, $S$ is not empty.

Let $n$ be the least element of $S.$

Then, since $m>0,$ $n>0,$ and $n-1\notin S,$ since $n$ is the least element of $S.$ So $f(n-1)<m$ and by (2.), $m\leq f(n)\leq f(n-1)+1<m+1.$ So $f(n)=m.$

---

We can make this constructive in your case, because we can construct $n_0$ such that $f(n_0)\geq m$ and then just check all the values $f(n)$ for all $n\leq n_0.$

Here, $n_0=dm$ then $f(n_0)=\left\lfloor ma+\frac{b}d\right\rfloor =ma\geq m.$

So this proof is constructive if property (3.) is constructive - that is, if there is a constructive function $g$ such that $f(g(m))\geq m$ for all $m.$

---

**Overkill**

We get a stronger result, if $g:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R^{\geq 0}$ is unbounded above such that $0\leq g(0)<1$ and $g(n+1)-g(n)\leq 1$ for all $n,$ then $f(n)=\lfloor g(n)\rfloor$ is a surjective function $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N.$

The well-ordering proof doesn't require $f$ to be increasing, just unbounded above and never increasing by more than $1.$

This is because we can always get bigger than $m,$ and if we can only increase at most by $1$ at a time, we must eventually hit $m.$

---

We can go further, and note if we only know $(2.),$ then if $n_1<n_2$ and $f(n_1)\leq m\leq f(n_2)$ then $m=f(n)$ for some $n_1\leq n\leq n_1.$

If we know $(1.)$ and $(2.),$ we know that the range must be either all natural numbers $\leq M$ for some $M,$ or the range must be all of $\mathbb N.$

But if we add $(3.),$ $f$ is unbounded, then the former case isn't possible, so the range must be all of $\mathbb N.$